# How to show that every bounded variation function on $[a,b]$ is differentiable a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

I'm struggling with this question for over a week now. I know the proposition is true, but haven't managed to prove it yet. any suggestions anyone?
($f$ is BV on $I$ if $$\sup\left\{\sum|f(b_k)-f(a_k)| :a_{k+1}\gt b_{k}\gt a_{k} ; a_k,b_k\in I\right\}\lt \infty)$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that monotonic functions are differentiable a.e.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every function of bounded variation is the difference of two monotonically non-decreasing functions. Monotonically non-decreasing functions are differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: please prove both these claims

Comment: @Snir: These results are quite standard. For example, you can find them both proven in Prof. Tao's book "An Introduction to Measure Theory", which can be found for free online (just ask Google!)

Comment: @Snir, see also Michael W. Botsko, An Elementary Proof of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem, The American Mathematical Monthly, 110 (2003), 834-838.

Comment: Snir didn't say his function is real-valued.  If it is complex valued: first show the real and imaginary parts are BV, then use the result here.