# Continuous or Differentiable but Nowhere Lipschitz Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, fractals, lipschitz-functions

1. What is a real valued function that is continuous on a close interval but not Lipschitz continuous on any subinterval?
2. What is a real valued function that is differentiable on a close interval but not Lipschitz continuous on any subinterval?

Comment: so the derivative has to be unbounded on any neighborhood. maybe look at $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ odd symmetrized and periodized, call this  $h(x)$. it's derivative is unbounded at $x=0$. then look at $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n h(nx)$ for some (summable) sequence $(c_n)$,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Continuous and nowhere Lipschitz

An example is given by the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous and nowhere differentiable. This can be justified in two ways:

- A Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere, by [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem).
- Direct inspection of the proof that the function is nowhere differentiable; the estimates used in the proof also imply it's nowhere Lipschitz ($|f(x+h)-f(x)|$ is estimated from below by $|h|^\alpha$ with $\alpha<1$, for certain $x,h$).

#### Differentiable and nowhere Lipschitz

There are no such examples: a differentiable function on an interval must be Lipschitz on some subinterval. The following is an adaptation of a part of [PhoemueX's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638647).

1. The function $f'$ is a pointwise limit of continuous functions: namely, $$f'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))$$
   where for each $n$, the expression under the limit is continuous in $x$.
2. Item 1 implies that $f'$ is continuous at some point $x_0$. This is a consequence of a theorem about functions of *Baire class 1*: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426096) for references.
3. Continuity at $x_0$ implies $f'$ is bounded on some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. The Mean Value Theorem then implies that $f$ is Lipschitz on this interval.

Comment: Thank you, sandwich. I will study your answer to part 2). Meanwhile, could you please think about part 1) for $f$ being continuous? I have now edited the question and separated it explicitly into two distinct parts. I should have done that at the beginning to prevent the confusion.

Comment: Okay, I expanded the answer.