# Is the Weierstrass function not Lipschitz continuous on any set of positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, lipschitz-functions, fractals

> Find a measurable set $A \subset\mathbb R$ with positive Lebesgue measure $\mu(A)>0$ such that the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is Lipschitz continuous on $A$, or show that no such set exists.

**Weierstrass function** is the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by the Fourier series
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n cos(b^n \pi x),
$$
where $a \in (0,1)$, $b$ is a positive odd integer, and $ab>1+\frac 3 2 \pi$. It is known to be continuous but not differentiable at any point.

Let me demonstrate the emphasize that $A$ can be any measurable set, not necessarily an interval. For example, the indicator function of the rational numbers is not Lipschitz continuous on any interval, but it is Lipschitz continuous on the set of irrational numbers (as it is constantly 0 on that domain).

A closely related question: [A continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ that is not Lipschitz continuous on any subset of a positive measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612690/1134951)

Comment: Take a look at Rademacher's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Thanks for the reference. Rademacher's theorem is relevant for a function that is Lipschitz continuous on an open set. In contact, here the set $A$ can be any measurable set with positive measure, so it might have no nonempty open subset.

Comment: I know, but it could be a good start point. And maybe there are relevant generalizations, I would do a research on it.

Comment: Also this work could be relevant https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02033.pdf

Comment: This seems like a pretty hard problem. Perhaps studying the proof that the Weierstrass function isn't differentiable in detail will give insight to do with bounds